# Phase portait of 3 by 3 matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the following linear system $x = Ax$, where $x\in\mathbb R^3$ and 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & -2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Draw the phase portrait nearby the origin as precisely, without computing the eigenvectors of the matrix.

I found $-3,2+i$ and $2-i$ are the eigenvalues. How could I figure out the  phase portrait nearby the origin. Please help me out to solve it.

Comment: drawing it out on $\mathbb{R}^3$? that's going to be messy

Comment: yea I know  any how can you provide me a hint @ More

Comment: its going to be a spiral  source on one plane, and then an asymptotic stable lines passing through the spiral center on that plane.

Comment: Now if you want to know which plane has the spiral source, you can go an compute the eigenvectors corresponding to 2+i and  2−i. Btw spiral source means the solution is moving away from the origin in a spiral way (opposite of a spiral asymptotic stable)

Comment: thank you , I got something I like to figure out with out using eigen vectors so that I was wondering.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to notice is the block-diagonal form of the matrix: it has diagonal blocks $(3)$  and $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & -2 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, with zeros elsewhere. This means that the system $x'=Ax$ *decouples* into an ODE for $x_1$, and an ODE system for $x_2,x_3$; there is no interaction between these two systems. It's easy to solve $x_1'=-3x_1$: exponential decay, the orbits approach the plane $x_1=0$.

The system for $(x_2,x_3)$ is planar,  and the eigenvalues (complex, with positive real part) indicate unstable spiral. Orbits spiral out counterclockwise, as you can see from a planar sketch.

Hence, the complete picture is: all trajectories approach the plane $x_1=0$, but move away from the origin of that plane in a spiraling fashion. It's sort of like the formation of a spiral galaxy from a shapeless cloud of gas.